# jquery animate one element after another

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a small sequence of animations with jQuery but cannot get it to work!

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
      <p>First line visable.</p>
      <span class="expand">Read more</span>
      <p class="fade">Line one</p>
      <p class="fade">Line two</p>
      <p class="fade">Line three</p>
      <p class="fade">Line four</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner {
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
    width:260px;
    padding:8px 14px 10px 14px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #CAC9C1;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    border-radius:8px }

    .inner span.expand {
        position:absolute;
        top:10px;
        right:10px;
        display:block;
        width:12px;
        height:12px;
        text-indent:-999em;
        cursor:pointer;
        background:transparent url(imgs/bg-sprite.png) no-repeat -580px -464px }

    .inner span.expand:hover { background-position:-580px -478px }

    .inner p.fade { display:none }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.char-lpool .expand').click(function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeOut({duration:200})
    $(this).parent().stop().animate(
        {top:"-240"}, 
        {duration:300},
        {easing: 'easeOutCubic'}), function() {
        $('.char-lpool .talk p.fade').stop().fadeIn({duration:200})
    }
});
```

By clicking on span.expand I want to first move div.inner up 240px whilst fading the span.expand out. After that has happened I want the hidden p.fade paragraphs to fade in.

I can only get all 3 animations to happen at the same time, or with the above code only the first 2 animations happen, the third does not work t all.

I know it's down to how I've written the jquery but cannot seem to get it working!!
Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see a `class="talk"` in your code, where's this coming from?

Comment: what version of jQuery do you work with?

Comment: You're referring to a `.char-lpool` that is not in your HTML. Is it the parent div?

Comment: sorry, edited the html but not the jquery class names – never mind Nicks figured it out below and solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call to [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is a bit off, the options should look like this:

```
$('.char-lpool .expand').click(function(){
  $(this).stop().fadeOut({duration:200})
         .parent().stop().animate(
           {top:"-240"}, 
           300,
           'easeOutCubic', 
           function() { $(this).find('p.fade').stop().fadeIn(200); }
         );
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jTQjg/)...*or* you can pass the last 3 options as a *single* parameter in an object, but not as distinct objects in separate parameters.

Comment: Thanks Nick – you seem to answer a few of my questions!